# How to access C# static method (might be in static class) from existing assemblies in Xslt?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

How do we access static methods from static class in Xslt? The static class is already defined in an assembly.

Here is the definition of the static class I want to refer

```
namespace Helper
{
    public static class StaticXsltHelper
    {
        public static double CalclutePerctange(int a, int b)
        {
            return b == 0 ? 0 : ((double)a * 100) / b;
        }
    }
}
```

How do we refer `StaticXsltHelper.CalclutePerctange` method in Xslt?

For non-static class and non-static methods I can use the following syntax

```
XslCompiledTransform t = new XslCompiledTransform();
XsltArgumentList l = new XsltArgumentList();
l.AddExtensionObject("a:b", new XsltHelper());
t.Load("XSLTFile.xslt", new XsltSettings(true, true), null);
using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter("XMLFileOut.xml"))
{
    t.Transform("XMLFile.xml", l, w);
}
```

Here is the definition of XsltHelper class

```
namespace Helper
{
    public class XsltHelper
    {
        public double CalclutePerctange(int a, int b)
        {
            return b == 0 ? 0 : ((double)a * 100) / b;
        }
    }
}
```

And the xslt will look like

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:prefix_1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:helper="a:b" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Entity">
      <Entity>
          <Percent>
            <xsl:value-of select="helper:CalclutePerctange(Value, Total)"/>
          </Percent>
```

But I did not find anything about static method.

Any kind of help/comment will be appreciated. Also I would like to know if this is possible or not.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Why can't you use that in a static method?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Basically I want to use the existing static methods in Xslt.

Comment: What existing static methods, how, to do what, and what happens when you try to use them?

Comment: let me add those definition in the question

Comment: @Servy - Do you think I should re-post the question?

Comment: No, just edit this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your main reason for wanting to do this?

It's likely that there isn't a way to use a static class for an XSLT extension object.

If the issue is that the methods are already defined in another assembly that you can't modify how about using something like this in the assembly that you can modify:

```
public class XsltHelper
{
        public double CalculatePerctange(int a, int b)
        {
             return StaticXsltHelper.CalculatePercentage(a, b);            
        }
}
```

Or you could use a singleton if your concern is that you're creating too many objects:

```
namespace Helper
{
    public class XsltHelper
    {
        private XsltHelper();
        public readonly XsltHelper Instance = new XsltHelper();

        public double CalculatePerctange(int a, int b)
        {
            return b == 0 ? 0 : ((double)a * 100) / b;
        }
    }
}
```

And then use:

```
l.AddExtensionObject("a:b", XsltHelper.Instance);
```

Comment: Yes, I was advised same solution elsewhere. We can only access non static methods.